# Unit Test UserManager<IdentityUser> in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-core

My application is an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API. I would like to test the following method (snipped):

```
public async Task<bool> GetClientsAsync()
{
     foreach (var user in await this.clientAdapter.Users().ToListAsync())
     {
          return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Normally the `clientAdapter` is calling `UserManager<IdentityUser>`'s property `Users`. So the code for the "real" clientAdapterlooks like that:

```
public IQueryable<IdentityUser> Users()
{
    return this.userManager.Users;
}
```

Now when I am testing the `clientAdapter` looks like the following:

```
private readonly List<IdentityUser> clientList;

public TestClientAdapter(){
     this.clientList= this.CreateClientList();
}

public IQueryable<IdentityUser> Users()
{
     return this.userList.AsQueryable();
}
```

The return type of the method `Users()` has to be `IQueryable<IdentityUser>` since thats the return value of the original class `UserManager<IdentityUser>`. Now if I execute the test I am getting the following error, as soon as it hit's the foreach loop (the problem is the `ToListAsync()` call):

> System.NotSupportedException: "Store does not implement `IQueryableUserStore<TUser>`."

If I change the loop from

```
foreach (var user in await this.clientAdapter.Users().ToListAsync())
{
    return true;
}
```

to

```
foreach (var user in this.clientAdapter.Users().ToList())
{
    return true;
}
```

Everything works fine.

My Problem:

I am not not able to mock the `UserManager` since the `UserManager` needs a `UserStore` which needs a `DBContext` which I dont know how to mock. And even if it was possbile to mock the `DBContext`, I think this would turn my unit test into an integration test and I dont want that. Plus it's probably not worth the effort. So I cannot just work with a mocked `Usermanager` and get the data from it.

My Question:

Is it possible to make the unit test pass, without changing the method I want to test?

**EDIT**

@CodeCaster:

The injected `clientAdapter` now looks like the following (snipped):

```
  public class TestClientAdapter: IClientAdapter, IQueryableUserStore<IdentityUser>
  {
  private readonly List<IdentityUser> clientList

  private UserManager<IdentityUser> testUserManager;

  public TestClientAdapter: ()
  {
     clientList= this.CreateclientList();

     this.testUserManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(this, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  }

  public IQueryable<IdentityUser> Users()
  {
     return this.testUserManager.Users;
  }

  IQueryable<IdentityUser> IQueryableUserStore<IdentityUser>.Users
  {
     get
     {
        return this.clientList.AsQueryable();
     }
  }
```

Now Iam getting another `Exception`:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException" in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll"
```

Comment: `ToListAsync` is not a standard Linq2SQL (aka `IQueryable<T>` extension method. It's [part](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/QueryableExtensions.cs#L922) of EntityFramework and as such it assumes certain preconditions, hence it can't work with a queryable List

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToListAsync` (among of other async methods like `AnyAsync`, etc.) is not a standard Linq2SQL (aka `IQueryable<T>`) extension method from `System.Linq.*`.

It's part of EntityFramework and as such it assumes certain preconditions, hence it can't work with a queryable List. Basically it's a wrapper around `query.AsAsyncEnumerable()` and `AsAsyncEnumerable` checks for the existence of `IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>` and/or `IAsyncEnumerableAccessor<TSource>` and if not there [throws the invalid operation exception](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/Extensions/Internal/QueryableExtensions.cs#L43).

There are two things you can do...

1. Use EF Core InMemoryDatabase for an integration test, which was made for integration tests
2. Refactor your code so `IQueryable<T>` doesn't leak outside of your repository or command/query handlers

Technically it may be possible to create an list which implements `AsAsyncEnumerable<T>` but I haven't tried it and most likely not working with `list.AsQueryable()` since it wraps the list somewhere below...

Comment: Thank you very much Tseng I spent 2 days on this. Iam now working with an  in memory Database and everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Let the clientAdapter you inject for tests also implement `IQueryableUserStore<TUser>`, as the UserManager casts it to that, and if that fails, throws the mentioned exception.

Comment: Hello CodeCaster thanks for your answer! I updated my question :-)